# Different display styles in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, displaystyle, mathabx

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{mathabx}


\begin{document}

\[\phi(\underbrace{r\cdots r}_{n-\text{veces}}) \qquad a\in A \qquad A\subseteq B \qquad\mathbb{Z}[i]\]

\end{document}
```

### Without `mathabx`:

[image]

### With `mathabx`:

[image]

### My question is:

Are there other packages that generate a similar effect `\usepackage{mathabx}`?

Comment: Yes, [`MnSymbol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mnsymbol) also provides a new math symbol font, which would cause a similar effect of "changing the notation" slightly.

Comment: ...but I don't know whether this answers your question. It still seems very broad to me.

Comment: @Werner -- Your answer is very useful for me.Thanks

Comment: Check out http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: There are several font packages that change the math font see e.g. http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html

Comment: What is the question? By the way, it should be `n\text{-veces}`.

Comment: @egreg -- the question is: what other packages provides a new math symbol font? And thanks for the correction

Comment: Other packages that change `\in`: `mathdesign`